# Tannaka without Yoneda?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory, symmetric-monoidal-categories

I am studying enriched categories, and as I wrote in my previous question [How is the morphism of composition in the enriched category of modules constructed?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404288/how-is-the-morphism-of-composition-in-the-enriched-category-of-modules-construct), this is very  difficult because there are no elementary books on this topic (so I hope that specialists in category theory will not kill me for what I am asking here).

In particular, I am looking from time to time at the Tannaka duality theorem for modules over monoids in a symmetric monoidal category, and I have a feeling that it can be proved without the [Yoneda lemma which is suggested as an instrument in this situation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tannaka+duality#ForVModules).

Am I right?

My impression is that everything must be simple, although I can't restore the details (and I hope that somebody will help me).

Suppose we have a monoid $A$ in a symmetric monoidal category $V$ and we consider the enriched category $_AV$ of modules over $A$, and the forgetful functor $F:{_AV}\to V$. It's easy to see that the family of maps
$$
\alpha_X:A\to[F(X),F(X)],
$$
where $\alpha_X$ corresponds to the $A$-module structure $\mu_X:A\otimes X\to X$ on $X\in\operatorname{Ob}({_AV})$, is what is called a *wedge* (from $A$ to $[F,F]$, or what is the correct term?).

Our aim is to prove that for any other wedge
$$
\beta_X:B\to[F(X),F(X)]
$$
there is a unique morphism $\omega:B\to A$ such that the diagrams in the family
[image: universal property of wedges]

(with $X\in\operatorname{Ob}({_AV})$) are commutative.

I guess that this $\omega$ is defined as the composition
$$
B\xrightarrow{\beta_A}[A,A] \xrightarrow{[\iota,1_A]}[I,A]
\xrightarrow{\rho_{[\iota,1_A]}^{-1}}[I,A]\otimes I
\xrightarrow{\operatorname{ev}^A_I}A
$$
(where $I$ is the unit in $V$, $\iota:I\to A$  the unit in the monoid $A$ and $\rho_{[\iota,1_A]}$ the right identity for $[\iota,1_A]$), but I don't understand how to prove the commutativity of diagrams (1).

In particular, the special case of (1)
[image: universal property of wedges with X = A]

is also a puzzle for me. This is the same as the equality of the morphisms
$$
B\otimes A\xrightarrow{\beta_A\otimes 1_A}[A,A]\otimes A \xrightarrow{[\iota,1_A]\otimes 1_A}[I,A]\otimes A
\xrightarrow{\rho_{[\iota,1_A]}^{-1}\otimes 1_A}[I,A]\otimes I\otimes A
\xrightarrow{\operatorname{ev}^A_I\otimes 1_A}A\otimes A \xrightarrow{\mu_A}A
$$
and
$$
B\otimes A\xrightarrow{\beta_A\otimes 1_A}[A,A]\otimes A \xrightarrow{\operatorname{ev}^A_A}A
$$
but why are they equal? I can check this only in the situation when $A$ is a usual monoid (in the category of sets) or a usual algebra.

I would appreciate if anybody could show this "bookkeeping" (as Fosco Loregian calls it), because for an outsider like me this is  incomprehensible. As I wrote in my previous question, each elementary step in this field is a problem, it requires weeks of pondering for me.

P.S. The applications of the Yoneda lemma are a gap in my education. If some kind person explains to me how it works, I will transfer this esoteric knowledge to the Moscow Mathematical School (with reference to this benefactor).

Comment: I haven't heard the term "wedge from $F$ to $F$" before. But I can make a good guess what it means: for every object $X \in {_A V}$, a morphism $\beta_X : A \to [F(X),F(X)]$, and, vitally, these morphisms should depend dinaturally on $X$. Equivalently, the corresponding map $\beta_X^\sharp : A \otimes F(X) \to F(X)$ should be natural in $X$ (as an object in $_A V$). Now specialize to $X=A$ (the regular module). Then $\beta_A$ is supposed to commute with the $A$-linear endomorphisms of $A$. Unpacking this commutation requirement should give the equation you are asking about.

Comment: @LSpice Paraphrasing Casca speaking to Cassius, most mathematical writing is "Greek to me".

Comment: You say you "check this ... in the situation when $$ is a usual monoid". What happens when you write that check always using enriched homs / working internally to $V$?

Comment: @LSpice I corrected this, although there was nothing insulting for anybody there. Theo is right, this is an expression in Russian, equivalent to "I understand nothing".

Comment: FWIW: Yoneda lemmas are really the fundamental theorems of category theory. Not using them is like not using the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute areas under a curve.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I must confess that I don't understand this technique of usage of the Yoneda lemma. Is there a text where this is explained for beginners?

Comment: (I deleted a comment suggesting an edit once the edit was made, so as not to clutter up the space, but it has since received two replies, so I had the opposite effect, and I don't want to leave it looking like two people were replying to nothing.  I am aware that the phrase in question is a common idiom, in both English and Russian, but thought that it was better avoided, since it could easily be done without any change to the meaning.)

Comment: (@LSpice Oh, I completely agree with your original comment. Indeed, common idioms are some of the most suspect parts of mathematical writing, and need to be used with very great care. Myself, I'm a big fan of Shakespearing puns, but would not use them in a main text, which I think of as like the primary lecture in a seminar. On the other hand, this comment section is more like the discussion over coffee or beer after the lecture: public, but still congenial.)

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd could you explain in an answer what you write here: "Unpacking this commutation requirement should give the equation you are asking about"  ?

Comment: Rather than me unpacking it, let me suggest a strategy. You know how to do the case when you have ordinary algebras or monoids. I assume this means: you know how to do the case when you have good access to "elements" of your algebras and modules. Probably every formula you write is linear in all of the elements that appear in it. If so, they you can usually implement those formulas internal to any enriching category by interpreting an expression like "for each $a \in A$" as "for each $a : A' \to A$", where not just $a$ but also $A'$ can vary.

Comment: The advantage then is that the *syntax* of "$a \in A$" is left unchanged --- you don't have to change any formulas --- even though the *semantics* (the meaning) is different. But with the new semantics, the original formulas will probably supply a proof. This is a general strategy and I encourage you to try it in this case.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd and this should work whenever I want to prove the commutativity of some diagram?

Comment: Well, I don't want to promise that it will always work, but it is a very good strategy.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I don't understand. Suppose we add two supplementary arrows $S\to A$ and $T\to B$ (or, I don't know, perhaps you mean that we must replace $A$ by $[S,A]$, and $B$ by $[T,B]$). Why it becomes easier to prove the necessary equalities?

Comment: Theo, and, excuse me, what is the correct term (for this "wedge from $F$ to $F$")?

Comment: You might want to have a look [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344571/is-tannaka-theory-easy).

Comment: @fosco it is my wish that you, or some other category theorist, write a book that discusses this "bookkeeping of proofs" in enriched categories in detail, with examples and exercises, so that beginners could understand. I asked many people, no one pointed out such a book to me. Moreover, even a text that explicitly formulates Tannaka's theorem for enriched categories, so that I could refer to it, is also not visible. If I want to use this statement, I have to prove it myself, but since I am not an expert, it takes me an order of magnitude more time than a specialist. This is very bad.

Comment: @emily what is the exact reference?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov (My apologies, I mistakenly sent the message when typing a "–".)

Comment: Johnson–Yau's writing style's _exactly_ like this; I think maybe you might find Chapters III.1–III.3 [here](https://nilesjohnson.net/drafts/Johnson_Yau_ring_categories.pdf) helpful (for an example of the level of detail there, see e.g. [here](https://nilesjohnson.net/drafts/Johnson_Yau_ring_categories.pdf#page=919)). [Their book on 2-categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06055) is also \*very\* good in this aspect. While it is not about enriched categories (except for the special case of Cat-enrichment), I think it is probably the best place to learn how to do these [1/2]

Comment: ...giant "diagram fillings" (i.e. starting with a big diagram whose commutativity you want to prove and then partitioning and filling it with smaller diagrams whose commutativity is known). Chapter 11 there is a [particularly striking](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.06055.pdf#page=356) example of this! [2/2]

Comment: (By the way, the issue you mention is [precisely](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2020/02/2dimensional_categories.html) what [led](https://twitter.com/NilesTopologist/status/1229398345350885377) them to writing it in this way!)

Comment: @Emily I don't understand, what they write, does it mean that if we want this "bookkeeping of proofs" to work, we need our enriched category to be a 2-category?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I understand "bookkeeping of proofs" as "writing proofs in full detail, without omitting steps just because they are unwieldy". In this sense, every area has its kind of bookkeeping, and in category theory it often occurs as having to prove the commutativity of large diagrams (as is the case here and in some of your recent questions)

Comment: I mentioned Johnson–Yau's book on 2-categories not because of its applicability to enriched categories (one does not need an enriched category to be a 2-category to be able to carry this "bookkeeping"), but rather because it's a good place to learn this technique (/"style of proof") in category theory.

Comment: I think \*right now\* you might find Chapters III.1 to III.3 of [their other book](https://nilesjohnson.net/drafts/Johnson_Yau_ring_categories.pdf) immediately helpful. I think it is probably the closest existing reference to your description above ("[...] a book that discusses this 'bookkeeping of proofs' in enriched categories in detail, with examples and exercises")

Comment: @Emily I am reading this Chapter III, I see what you call "diagram fillings", this is more or less how I used to prove the commutativity of diagrams myself, but I don't see there traces of this philosophy  of passage from "$\forall a\in A$" to "$\forall a:A'\to A$". From Theo's comparison with  computing areas under a curve I got an impression that there is an  algorithm, similar to Newton's calculus, that allows to fill big diagrams (in cases when they indeed are commutative). That is not true?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine what do you think about all this?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I think Theo is referring to how one strategy for doing this "diagram fillings" is to first start with a proof using elements in a special case and then rewrite it into a proof using diagrams for the general case (this reminds me a bit of proofs in homological algebra for $\mathsf{Mod}_R$ vs. a general abelian category). This is the same strategy used by Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine in their [reply](https://mathoverflow.net/a/404300) to your other question (as said there: "a simple algebraic proof should become a reasonably simple categorical proof").

Comment: So while there's no general algorithm for this kind of "diagram filling" proofs, this is often a useful intermediate step. (By the way, while it is _not directly related_ to the situation here, maybe one useful thing to mention might be the notion of the ["internal language of a topos"](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~gael/xxi/files/slides_posters/Blechschmidt.pdf), which formalises a bit this passage from elements $a\in A$ to morphisms $A'\to A$. See also [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+element) and [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/global+element).)

Comment: @Emily I understand what they are talking about, but if this is considered as a "good strategy", then there must be texts where this strategy is discussed in detail. Where are those texts? Theo compares this technique with Newton's calculus, but the difference is that there are thousands of textbooks where Newton's calculus is thoroghly explained with lots of illustrations and exercises. While the calculus in category theory remains "knowledge for the members of club only".

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I'm not sure, but I think it's a bit hard to find references explaining precisely this kind of proof strategy. I think this is due to both the difference in age between calculus and category theory, and also to their relative applicability: almost everyone in mathematics needs to know calculus, but knowing how to do these "diagram fills" is a much more specific skill.

Comment: Incidentally, from what I understand, Theo was comparing the fundamental theorem of calculus to the Yoneda lemma, rather than to this strategy, and in this case there are indeed a number of references explaining the Yoneda lemma in detail. On this latter point, could you please clarify a bit what you mean when writing "The applications of the Yoneda lemma are a gap in my education"? (E.g. are you specifically confused about the "enriched Yoneda lemma", but not about the "ordinary" Yoneda lemma?)

Comment: @Emily for me, all forms of Yoneda's lemma are theoretical knowledge, without practice. Are there textbooks that explain with examples how one can prove statements in category theory using Yoneda's lemma (ordinary or enriched)?

Comment: And from people's explanations (here and before) I got an impression that this technique comes exactly from Yoneda's lemma. Is this different?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I believe this technique _doesn't_ come from the Yoneda lemma. I personally think of it as being somewhat similar to generalisation: when carrying the latter, we often have in hands a definition with a number of equivalent characterisations, but only some of which generalise well to other contexts. For example, we could say define a group as a set $X$ with a binary operation satisfying a number of axioms, or as a set with a map $X\times X\to X$ making appropriate diagrams commute.

Comment: While both definitions give the same object for sets, only the latter one makes sense in a general category, giving the notion of a [group object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object). Similarly, In the context of your earlier question, we have an algebraic proof based on elements (analogous to the binary operation definition of a group) and a categorical proof by a large diagram filling (analogous to the set with a map making some diagrams commute definition).

Comment: Regarding applications of the Yoneda lemma, I think the first thing to note is that we often encounter a slight abuse of language in the literature in that a number of its corollaries are also often called just "the Yoneda lemma". Strictly speaking, the Yoneda lemma may be stated as "we have an isomorphism "$\mathrm{Nat}(h_U,\mathcal{F})\cong\mathcal{F}(U)$, natural in $U$". Perhaps its three most important immediate corollaries are the following:

Comment: 1) "The Yoneda embedding is fully faithful: a natural transformation $h_X\Rightarrow h_Y$ is the same thing as a morphism $X\to Y$", 2) We have $A\cong B$ iff $h_A\cong h_B$ 3) Objects representing a functor are unique if they exist: if $h_A\cong\mathcal{F}$ and $h_B\cong\mathcal{F}$, then $A\cong B$.

Comment: One often uses "Corollary 3" above to construct "universal objects". For example, the module of Kähler differentials is the ["module representing the functor of derivations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differential#Definition_using_derivations) in that we have
$$\mathrm{Hom} _{\mathsf{Mod}_S}(\Omega _{S/R},M)\cong\mathrm{Der}_{R}(S,M).$$
That it exists is not a category theory proof: we have to construct it (say as a free $S$-module on symbols $\mathrm{d}s$ quotiented by certain relations).

Comment: However, once we have done that, its uniqueness is automatic: if we have
$$\mathrm{Hom} _{\mathsf{Mod}_S}(X,M)\cong\mathrm{Der}_{R}(S,M)$$
for some other $S$-module $X$, then "the Yoneda lemma" (more precisely, corollary 3 above) says that $X\cong\Omega _{S/R}$.This same situation happens in a very very large number of other constructions, including e.g. the sheafification of a presheaf and the analytification of a complex algebraic variety, but also for category-theoretic examples: co/limits (or e.g. adjoint functors) if they exist are unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: This situation is a bit similar to that in the theory of distributions: every nice function $f$ (analogous to an object $X$ of a category) gives rise to a distribution $\phi\mapsto\int_Uf(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ (analogous to a representable functor $h_X$), and so in general we could start with a distribution $T$ (analogous to a general functor $\mathcal{F}$) and ask if there is some function $f$ giving rise to it: if there is, then it is automatically unique: if there exists another function $g$ giving rise to the distribution $T$, then we have $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Corollary 2 ($h_A\cong h_B\implies A\cong B$) is often applied when we want to prove that two objects are isomorphic, but to do so we have to consider morphisms into them (say because we have to the natural bijection provided by some adjunction). A great example of this is the proof of [Proposition 3.1 here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category#TensorHomIsoInternalizes).

Comment: Some nice applications of "Corollary 1" ("The Yoneda embedding is fully faithful: a natural transformation $h_X\Rightarrow h_Y$ is the same thing as a morphism $X\to Y$, i.e. $\mathrm{Nat}(h_X,h_Y)\cong\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$") that don't reduce to "Corollaries 2 and 3" are the following: 1) When setting up the functor of points formalism in algebraic geometry, we need the statement "a morphism of schemes $X\to Y$ is precisely the same thing as a natural transformation between the associated functors of points of $X$ and $Y$", which is a special case of Corollary 1.

Comment: 2) [Riehl's _Category theory in context_, Corollary 2.2.9](https://emilyriehl.github.io/files/context.pdf#thm.2.2.9): "Every row operation on matrices with $n$ rows is defined by left multiplication by some $n\times n$ matrix, namely the matrix obtained by performing the row operation on the identity matrix." 3) [Riehl's _Category theory in context_, Corollary 2.2.10](https://emilyriehl.github.io/files/context.pdf#thm.2.2.10): Cayley's theorem "Any group is isomorphic to a subgroup of a permutation group."

Comment: 4) To construct the limit and colimit functors, we need to show that a natural transformation $\alpha\colon D\to D'$ between two diagrams $D$ and $D'$ induces a morphism $\lim(D)\to\lim(D')$. One way to do this is to consider the composition
$$h_{\lim(D)}\cong\mathrm{Nat}(\Delta_{(-)},D)\xrightarrow{\alpha_*}\mathrm{Nat}(\Delta_{(-)},D')\cong h_{\lim(D')}$$
and then apply Corollary 1 to get a morphism $\lim(D)\to\lim(D')$.

Comment: The Yoneda lemma per se ($\mathrm{Nat}(h_U,\mathcal{F})\cong\mathcal{F}(U)$) is used in proofs of some propositions in category theory, such as the [density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_theorem_(category_theory)#Proof)).

Comment: Finally, I think a good reference for all this is [Riehl's _Category theory in context_](https://emilyriehl.github.io/files/context.pdf), in particular Chapter 2. There are also a number of applications of the Yoneda lemma there in later chapters, such as e.g. [Proposition 3.1.7](https://emilyriehl.github.io/files/context.pdf#thm.3.1.7) or Section 4.4.

Comment: @Emily this is very interesting, thank you very much! I am reading this.

Comment: And it's strange that nobody in Russia could explain this.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov It's my pleasure, I hope this helps! :)

Comment: @Emily this is impressive, but for applying the (enriched) Yoneda lemma to Tannaka's theorem, we need the category $_AV$ to be small. Usually it is not small, how is this resolved?  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+Yoneda+lemma

Comment: @Emily moreover, even if there was no this problem with the smallness of ${_AV}$, I must say that I do not understand how the author in nLab expects the readers to follow his instructions in proving Tannaka's theorem: Yoneda formally gives only the equality $\operatorname{Nat}({_AV}(A,-),F)=A$, and to deduce from this the equality $\operatorname{End}(F)=A$ it seems that we need a lemma that proves the isomorphism between $F$ and ${_AV}(A,-)$. But this looks like a separate problem in enriched categories.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I'm not sure how to fix the smallness problem (though probably it's not "hard", I'm just particularly bad at this!), and have asked about it [here](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/744/#Item_57). Ignoring this issue though I think we can understand the proof as follows: we can identify $_{A}V$ with $\mathbf{Fun}_V(\mathbf{B}A,V)$, and under this identification $F$ becomes the precomposition $V$-functor
$$[\bullet]^*\colon\mathbf{Fun}_V(\mathbf{B}A,V)\to\underbrace{\mathbf{Fun}_V(\mathbf{pt}_V,V)}_{\cong V}$$
along the functor $[\bullet]\colon\mathbf{pt}_V\to\mathbf{B}A$..

Comment: ..picking the unique object $\bullet$ of $\mathbf{B}A$. Now we note that by the Yoneda lemma, the $V$-functor that picks an $A$-module $M$, viewed as a $V$-functor $M\colon\mathbf{B}A\to V$, and outputs its evaluation $M(\bullet)$ at the object $\bullet$ of $\mathbf{B}A$ is $V$-naturally isomorphic to the $V$-functor $\mathbf{Nat}_V(h_{\bullet},-)$, since
$$\mathbf{Nat}_V(h_{\bullet},M)\cong M(\bullet)$$
by the enriched Yoneda lemma. So we have $F\cong[\bullet]^*$, and also
$$[\bullet]^*\cong\mathbf{Nat}_V(h_{\bullet},-),$$
so $F\cong\mathbf{Nat}_V(h_{\bullet},-)$ too.

Comment: Now we can compute $\mathrm{End}(F)$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{End}(F) &\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathbf{Nat}_V(F,F)\\
&\cong\mathbf{Nat}_V(\mathbf{Nat}_V(h_{\bullet},-),\mathbf{Nat}_V(h_{\bullet},-))\tag{since $F\cong\mathbf{Nat}_V(h_{\bullet},-)$}\\
&\cong\mathbf{Nat}_V(h_{\bullet},h_{\bullet})\tag{by the enriched Yoneda lemma}\\
&\cong\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathbf{B}A}(\bullet,\bullet)\tag{by the enriched Yoneda lemma again}\\
&\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}A.
\end{align*}

Comment: I will drown myself.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov What do you mean?

Comment: This is an expression in Russian: when the work becomes overwhelming, it's easier to drown yourself than to finish it.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov This is a very relatable feeling, and also a justified one =/. I just want to mention that I'm happy to help if you'd still like to understand this; it's admittedly quite confusing (FWIW I got confused at some points when writing the above, too)

Comment: @Emily I think you should edit that article in nLab, because this instruction is too vague: "Apply the enriched Yoneda lemma verbatim as for the statement about permutation representations as above".

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov This is a good idea; I've copied over some of the comments above to there.

Comment: @Emily is it possible to remove the condition of delooping in the Tannaka theorem? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tannaka+duality#ForVModules

Comment: @DmitriPavlov can you recommend some reading about $\lambda$-presentable categories, that you mention here: https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/744/#Item_57 ? And do your words mean that in the formulation of the enriched Yoneda lemma it is possible to drop the condition that the category $C$ is small? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+Yoneda+lemma

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov We are using deloopings there to be able to apply the enriched Yoneda lemma (we need to write $\mathsf{Mod}_A$ as the V-functor category $\mathbf{Fun}_V(\mathbf{B}A,V)$ for that). I think we shouldn't avoid it though (even if we could), as it is a simple idea (though its chosen presentation in the [delooping](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping) page in the nLab is a bit scary): a category with one object is 'just' a monoid, so we can think of categories as monoids with many objects. Similarly, V-enriched categories are monoids in V with many objects.

Comment: The delooping of a monoid is "just" the construction that allows us to think of monoids as particular instances of categories (=monoids with many objects).
(Explicitly, $\mathbf{B}A$ is the V-enriched category having: 1) A single object $\bullet$, 2) Its unique Hom-object given by $$\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathbf{B}A}(\bullet,\bullet)\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}A$$

Comment: $\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}\newcommand{\a}{\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathbf{B}A}(\bullet,\bullet)}$3) Its composition map
$$\circ^{\mathbf{B}A}_{\bullet,\bullet,\bullet}\colon\underbrace{\a\otimes_V\a}_{\defeq A\otimes_V A}\to\underbrace{\a}_{\defeq A}$$
at $(\bullet,\bullet,\bullet)$ given by the multiplication morphism $\mu_{A}\colon A\otimes_V A\to A$ of $A$, and finally 4) its unit map
$$\mathbf{1}^{\mathbf{B}A}_{\bullet}\colon\mathbf{1}_V\to\underbrace{\a}_{\defeq A}$$
at $\bullet$ given by the unit morphism $\eta_{A}\colon\mathbf{1}_V\to A$ of the monoid $A$ in $V$.)

Comment: Incidentally, I think your ping to Dmitri didn't work: only users who have commented here can be notified. (I have relayed your question to Dmitri [here](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/744/#Item_59))

Comment: @Emily I don't understand you. I am not against using delooping in the proof, but is it possible to remove it from the formulation of the theorem? I am not fluent in this, in particular, this detail remains unclear to me.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: Locally Presentable
and Accessible Categories by Adámek and Rosický seems to be pretty good.  The initial sections give a good overview of the relevant theory.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov is it possible that the trick that you suggest here - https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/744/#Item_57 - allows to get rid of the requirement that $C$ is a small category in the enriched Yoneda lemma? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+Yoneda+lemma

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov From the formulation yes! We can state it as follows: "Let $F\colon\mathsf{Mod}_A\to\mathcal{V}$ be the forgetful $\mathcal{V}$-functor sending an $A$-module $(M,\lambda_M)$ to its underlying object $M$. Then we have an isomorphism $\mathbf{End}(F)\cong A$".

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: It may not be necessary to use this trick after all.  It appears that the enriched Yoneda lemma for large enriched categories can be deduced from the weak Yoneda lemma for large enriched categories.  I answered on the nForum: https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/744/#Item_57

Comment: @Emily if it is possible to remove this from the formulation of the theorem, you should do this. Each time when something can be simplified it is our duty to simplify it.

Comment: And, gentlemen, you should publish these results in a journal, because, in my opinion, they are very important. I don't know who will be the author, or whether you agree that this is important, but in any case I need a reference. I can't refer to nLab, this will not be accepted by the publishers that I usually deal with.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I'm a bit wary of editing the statement there (in part because one would lose some of the hyperlinks), though I've added a simplified version ("slogan") just above it.